# I need to adjust relative layout to 480 x 800 screen

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i have design an calculator app 
in nexus 6 resolution but when  i play the app in 400 x 800 hdpi it all break 
mean app don't look same one button on other corner and one on other hope you got it i want my application to work on all screen sizes my app is design in relative layout i don't want to change 
help thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
android:id="@+id/plus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/minus"
android:layout_marginEnd="-103dp"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/minus"
android:text="+" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/Relative_Number"
android:layout_width="163dp"
android:layout_height="59dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="241dp"
android:text="Click Me" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/divide"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/plus"
android:layout_marginEnd="116dp"
android:text="/" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/minus"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginStart="107dp"
android:layout_marginTop="285dp"
android:text="-" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/multiply"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/plus"
android:text="*" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="381dp"
android:layout_height="63dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="168dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/result"
android:layout_width="381dp"
android:layout_height="63dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/num1"
android:layout_width="381dp"
android:layout_height="63dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="106dp"
android:hint="Please Enter Your First Number"
android:inputType="number" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/num2"
android:layout_width="381dp"
android:layout_height="63dp"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="187dp"
android:hint="Please Enter Your 2nd Number"
android:inputType="number" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Much of your design uses de-facto absolute positioning. Try to position elements relative to each other. Only if this is not possible for some reason, use dimensions that depend on the screen size.

Comment: @Jasir ali -  you need to practice with all layout

Comment: and dont put static size use SDP for all predefine devices- https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: RelativeLayout is only not a good or proper way to achieve your task

Comment: can any one provide me solution or code

Comment: create a separate folder for different screen size and place your separate layout folder in it.